# help with metaphor

Tags: metaphors

I'm trying to come up with a metaphor for failed.

I failed like a car out of gas.

Something like that or better.

Having trouble thinking of things, anyone out there creative?

Comment: That's a *simile*. A metaphor would say that you *were* a car out of gas.

Comment: I screwed up like a bolt holding a metal plate to the bottom of a car.

Comment: I blew it like a balloon.

Comment: I messed up like a teenager's bedroom floor.

Comment: I failed like a stupid person on a test.

Comment: Be warned, this is just the beginning.

Comment: I [***fluffed it***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fluffer) like [Ken Dodd's tickling stick](https://www.cornwalllive.com/whats-on/ken-dodds-tickling-sticks-came-1328591) on a porn movie set.

Comment: ...I ***caved in*** like a spelaeologist / speleologist / spelunker...

Comment: All the sentences making comparison with the help of **like** or **as** are examples of **simile**, not *metaphor*.

Answer (score 1):

To be a really apt metaphor, or a simile - since you are using "like", you need to consider more about the "fail".

Did you fail because you didn't try hard enough - "I failed like a kid who didn't study for a test".

Did you fail because it was too much for you - "I failed like a little kid trying to climb Mt Everest."

Did you fail because people didn't help you - "I failed like an actor trying to perform Julius Caesar by herself."

Did you fail because people worked against you - "I failed like a marathon runner dragging a wagon full of kids."

I'm not suggesting any of these similes directly, but suggesting how you can find an appropriate one yourself. Creative writing is finding the combination of words that pleases you. Good luck.